# How should Distant Worlds and its expansion packs be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Distant worlds](http://www.matrixgames.com/products/379/details/Distant.Worlds) currently has two expansion packs:

- Distant worlds - Return of the Shakturi
- Distant worlds - Legends

There are currently no questions about the base game, and a limited number about each of the expansion sets. As a result these expansion sets have their own tag, but there is no generic distant worlds tag.

- [Return of the Shakturi questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distant-worlds-shakturi)
- [Legends questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distant-worlds-shakturi)

Should the questions about the expansion sets also be tagged with a generic distant-worlds tag?

Comment: Is the base game playable without any expansions? That'd be the first question I ask before trying to expand upon any sort of taxonomical issues with its tags - Matrix Games' website just provides links to buy the expansions, not the base game, inferring (to me) that there's no base game strictly speaking, and obviating the need for a tag for it in general.

Comment: Yes, there is a base game and playable without expansions. The links for buying the base game are on the left of the product page, where there are options for to buy the downloadable version or order a boxed version. The base game is playable without expansions, but the expansions are not playable without the base game.